# Show Image source

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to show image source in my website. Just like the image given below.
[image]

I don't want to use `<div>`, `<span>` or any other extra html tags.

**Is it possible to show the image source just using `<img>` tag or by adding some css?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to show attribution for the image, you can use the `<figure>` element. You still have to have your attribution source separate though.

```
<figure>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <figcaption>Photo by Name</figcaption>
</figure>
```